# Какая связь между частями?

Tags: сложные-прилагательные

Написание слова "беспроцентно-выигрышный" объясняется так:

> беспроцентный, но выигрышный.

Почему так? Ведь это "выигрыш без процентов" (комиссий), значит связь здесь подчинительная.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В этом сложном прилагательном **сочинительная связь** между его частями. В этом случае надо правильно понимать **значение самого слова, а также союза НО**.

**1. Из словаря**
**БЕСПРОЦЕНТНЫЙ**. Не имеющий процентных начислений. Б-ая ссуда. Б. заём.
ВЫИГРЫШНЫЙ. 1. Приносящий выигрыш, дающий право на получение выигрыша. В. билет. В. заем. 2. Способствующий успеху; благоприятный, выгодный, удачный

**2. Розенталь** Раздел 9. Правописание сложных слов »» § 39. Сложные прилагательные http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=49
**Пункт 8**. Пишутся через дефис сложные прилагательные, образованные из двух и более основ, обозначающих равноправные понятия; между частями таких прилагательных в их начальной форме можно вставить сочинительный союз И или НО:
торгово-промышленный капитал (ср. торговый, и промышленный)
**беспроцентно-выигрышный заём** (ср. беспроцентный, но выигрышный)

3. Итак, понятия *беспроцентный* и *выигрышный* **действительно равноправные**, что видно из словаря, а И и НО — это сочинительные союзы. Однако союз НО относится к группе **противительных** союзов, в отличие от **соединительного** союза И.

Здесь союз НО имеет частное **противительно-возместительное значение**: какой-либо **недостаток** признака в первой части возмещается каким-либо его **достоинством** во второй части. Действительно, беспроцентный заем — это недостаток (обычно заем бывает процентный, за деньги). Но этот недостаток возмещается его достоинством, а именно тем, что он дает право на выигрыш (как лотерейный билет).

4. Можно объяснить так значение союза НО: беспроцентно-выигрышный — это хотя **беспроцентный, но (зато) выигрышный.** (В этом обороте двойной сочинительный союз ХОТЯ...НО.)

Answer (score 1):

Я слышу сочинительную, т. е. не сколь выигрышный, а

беспроцентный и выигрышный, -

нас информируют о двух равных по важности качествах.